# Extract repeated patterns from a single-line string using Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
attr one = 1 attr two = 2
```

I would like to extract each `attr x = y` (where x and y can be anything **including whitespace**, not just numbers for example: attr name = Jonah).

I tried the following pattern: `Regex pattern = new Regex(@"attr\s+(?<name>.*)\s+=\s+(?<value>.*)")` but it returns the entire string in a single match and doesn't separate them.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: `attr\s+(?<name>\S*)\s+=\s+(?<value>\S*)`? `\S` matches any non-whitespace chars. Can there be whitespaces in keys and values?

Comment: In keys no, but values yes. For example: attr name = John Carmack

Comment: ultimately it depend on what's valid for both the key can value. basically as spaces allow, how about equals signs? You want to clarify the set of rules for both the key and values because at the moment your regex says take everything for name include the space and '=' which is where your issue lies.

Comment: You could simply split your string of matches of the regular expression `\ +(?=attr )`. (I escaped the first space merely for readability.) [ref](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=+%2b%28%3f%3dattr+%29&i=attr+one+%3d+1+attr+two+%3d+2%0d%0aattr+one+%3d+one+two+three+attr+two+%3d+3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
\battr\s+(?<name>\S*)\s+=\s+(?<value>.*?)(?=\s+attr\s|\z)
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5Cbattr%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Cname%3E%5CS*%29%5Cs%2B%3D%5Cs%2B%28%3F%3Cvalue%3E.*%3F%29%28%3F%3D%5Cs%2Battr%5Cs%7C%5Cz%29&i=attr%20one%20%3D%201%20attr%20two%20%3D%202%0D%0Aattr%20one%20%3D%20one%20two%20three%20attr%20two%20%3D%203)

**Details**

- `\battr` - a whole word `attr`
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<name>\S*)` - Group "name": 0 or more non-whitespace chars
- `\s+=\s+`  - a `=` char enclosed with 1+ whitespaces
- `(?<value>.*?)` - Group "value": any 0 or more chars other than a newline as few as possible...
- `(?=\s+attr\s|\z)` - that is immediately followed with 1+ whitespaces, `attr` and a whitespace, or with the end of string.

See a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/3gwmju) (assuming the `names` are all unique):

```
var text = "attr one = one two three attr two = 3";
var dct = Regex.Matches(text, @"\battr\s+(?<name>\S*)\s+=\s+(?<value>.*?)(?=\s+attr\s|\z)")
        .Cast<Match>()
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Groups["name"].Value, p => p.Groups["value"].Value); 
foreach (var kvp in dct)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} -> {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value);
```

Output:

```
one -> one two three
two -> 3
```